# Best way to combine $z(x,y)$ and $x(y)$ on the same plot

Tags: plotting

**Ingredients**

(1) function $z(x,y)$, plotted on some domain $\Omega$

(2) function $x_{1}(y)$

**Goal**

Show them on the same plot.

**Sample**

(1) A contour plot

[image: contour]

(2) Function plot

[image: astar]

Comment: Have you seen `Show[]`?

Comment: @J. M.: Ahh! You are correct. My problem was the function was defined incorrectly; that's why it looked wrong. Your careful reading is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ J. M: Repair post or delete?

Comment: That's up to you.